# How do I detect two fingers at touchstart in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using .on("touchstart mousedown",function (e) {pTouchDown(e)});

Its working with one finger touch, but I want to do some operation with two-finger touch too.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The touch events contain a property, called `touches`, which contains all the touch points available. You can read more about TouchEvents [on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent)

In your case, you would need to check the length of the `touches` property:

```js
someElement.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
  if(e.touches.length > 1) {
    // ... do what you like here
  }
});
```

Or with jQuery:

```js
$someElement.on('touchstart', function (e) {
  if (e.touches.length > 1) {
    // ... do what you like here
  }
});
```