# How to disable scroll on touch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, touch-event

I have a component in react on which `touchmove` event should be disabled. I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
parentRef.current.addEventListener("touchMove", e => e.preventDefault(), false)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent default handling of touch events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541173/how-to-prevent-default-handling-of-touch-events)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the [touch-action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action) property in your CSS file to remove the scroll event from your html body or an element. Add the below code in your code.

```
touch-action: none;
-ms-touch-action: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if this device has innerWidth below certain pixels then set `overflow:hidden` and height & width to `100vh` & `100vw` respectively  to the parentRef in useEffect

Comment: Also, add a fixed element that has the height and width, so it shows on top of anything, and removes scrolling fully.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent scrolling using CSS on React rendered components, we can set the overflow CSS property to hidden with JavaScript.

For instance, we write:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  }, []);

  return <div>hello world</div>;
}
```

to set the overflow CSS of the body element to hidden when the component mounts with:

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

The useEffect callback only runs when the component mounts since we passed in an empty array as the 2nd argument of useEffect.